# The entity type 'UserGroupLink' requires a primary key to be defined. This is a many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I'm getting *The entity type 'UserGroupLink' requires a primary key to be defined.* I got this error when I run *Add-Migration* in Package Manager Console. I tried various stackoverflow answers, none of them is working for me. **User** may be part of any number of **UserGroups** and **UserGroup** can have one or more **User**. **UserGroupLink** is the table bridges this relationship as below Fluent Api configuration. Please help me in this. I followed this article https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework.Docs/blob/live/entity-framework/core/modeling/keys.md#fluent-api.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<UserGroup>().Property(u => u.UserGroupId).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserGroup>().Property(u => u.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserGroup>().HasOne(u => u.Project).WithMany(p => p.UserGroups).HasForeignKey(f => f.ProjectId);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(u => u.Email);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Email).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(u => u.Role).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(50);

modelBuilder.Entity<UserGroupLink>().HasKey(l => new { l.UserGroupId, l.Email }); //Key is already defined here. Still error.
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserGroupLink>().HasOne(l => l.UserGroup).WithMany(u => u.UserGroupLinks).HasForeignKey(l => l.UserGroupId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserGroupLink>().HasOne(l => l.User).WithMany(u => u.UserGroupLinks).HasForeignKey(l => l.Email);
```

Class

```
public class UserGroupLink
{
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserGroupId { get; set; }        
    public UserGroup UserGroup { get; set; }
    public UserGroupLink()
    {

    }
    public UserGroupLink(User user, UserGroup userGroup)
    {
        User = user;
        UserGroup = userGroup;
    }
}
public class UserGroup
{
    public int UserGroupId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int ProjectId { get; protected set; }
    public Project Project { get; protected set; }
    public IList<UserGroupLink> UserGroupLinks { get; set; }
}
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
    public IList<UserGroupLink> UserGroupLinks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Have you added the migration and updated database, before running the app?

Comment: I got this error, when I run "Add-Migration" in Package Manager Console.

Comment: Can you post use and usergroup class also

Comment: I've added now.